# why can't move file to recycle bin?

Tags: windows-xp, recycle-bin

i'm using windows xp,
my computer suddenly goes weird and crazy,

usually when we select a file and press delete key, an alert dialog will appear asking whether the file should be moved to recycle bin.

but in my computer now, when pressing delete key, it doesn't show the move-to-recycle-bin dialog, it shows the delete-completely dialog (like shift+del)
(without doubts, my shift keys are not stuck, or i can't type this question in lowercase letters)

any body knows what's happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the Recycle Bin properties and uncheck "Do not send files to the Recycle Bin".

Comment: yes, tks vazquez